# Python print from a text file with parameters

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

Trying to write a program that will look through a text file containing the NYTimes bestselling books and let the user search and print a book from the list.

Currently have this code that prints the line containing the name of the book they type:

```
def lookup(): 
    file= input("Please enter the text file path: ")
    search = input("Enter the books you wish to search for:   ")
    search = [word.strip() for word in search.lower().split(",")]
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = "\n" + line  
            for word in search:
                if word.lower() in line.lower():
                    print(line)

lookup()
```

How would I let the user search for a year range? The txt file contains the book name, author, year published, etc. all separated by 1 tab space.

Comment: Searching for ranges is a little tricky, but FWIW, you can read your data in a more convenient way using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. I suggest reading your file into a list of dictionaries, one dictionary per book.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Pandas read_csv function?

```
import pandas as pd

#reads in the tab delimited file
df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter ='\t')

#gives all rows where the book year is 2000 or 2001
#You can pass the list of years generated by the user to the isin() function
df.loc[df.loc[:,'Year'].isin([2000, 2001]),:]
```

This solution of course assumes that you can read the file into memory.